# How to use VScode (on Win10) to do remote dev on Alpine Linux guestVM running in Virtualbox?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, alpine-linux

Have been learning Go-lang development on a small Alpine Linux 3.13 based guestVM on Virtulbox on my Windows 10 Enterprise host. I noticed that VScode seems to support Alpine Linux >=3.9 via containers or WSL2 in remote-SSH development mode using the extension. However, in spite of setting up the guestVM to have `wget`, `git` (as required) and ensuring seamless SSH access from the host (tested using Windows 10 inbuilt SSH client) to login without requiring password, VScode fails to connect to the VM. Is this really an unsupported configuration ? Any manual workarounds to make it work.

PS> I do not enable or use Hyper-V or WSL2 or docker containers on this host.

Comment: Additional resources: [Running glibc programs](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs) (from Alpine wiki) and [frolvlad/alpine-glibc](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/) (third-party Docker image with glibc packages already installed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently(just) added an entry in vscode-remote issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6347#issuecomment-1079430646

Following is the what needed to be done on the remote alpine box/vm:

```
# This is what make vscode remote-ssh work
apk add gcompat libstdc++ curl bash

# As alpine by default use busybox and some common utilities behave differently, like grep
apk add grep dropbear-scp dropbear-ssh

# Add zsh if using zsh shell
apk add zsh
```

The warning still show up, but work normally so far. I can verify docker extension works in this setup.