# Remote development with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access, alpine-linux

I'm running Alpine 3.12 with the latest 64-bit kernel. Installed VS extension for remote server ssh connections and by trying to connect, I see that the process has downloaded a folder ".vscode-server" on my remote server, which means that the connection happened, but after loading for some time I receive this message "The remote host may not meet VS Code Server's prerequisites for glibc and libstdc++". I did some googling on this, and I see that a few people were having trouble as they didn't have enough space on their server storage to install some libraries, but this is not the case for me. The extension itself provides me with this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux#_remote-host-container-wsl-linux-prerequisites explaining that there could be problems for Alpine based systems, but it should work anyways, but I can't quite find the problem. Maybe someone has faced this issue and can guide me to the solution?

Comment: I think one of Alpine's features is that it doesn't use glibc. See [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs) and [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/).

Comment: It's a fair point that the server is musl-based Alpine Linux, but even with that it could have some limitations, but the connection should happen anyways

Comment: I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623383/1810391

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use VScode (on Win10) to do remote dev on Alpine Linux guestVM running in Virtualbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657706/how-to-use-vscode-on-win10-to-do-remote-dev-on-alpine-linux-guestvm-running-in)

Comment: this solution finally allows me to use the extension!